# How to Show Category List With Corresponding Links?

Tags: plugin-development, posts, categories, plugin-list-category-post

i want to do a research in Category List Area.
I'll Explain Here...
Now I have 4 Categories Like 1,2,3,4.
First of all it needs to show in the category pages Horizontally.Next is, While Clicking on Any Category  it will show the articles from only that category in this thumbnail format, this also should be in a format that allows for 40 or 50 potential articles to be shown this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the category link URL, add he category ID.
Then when you click the link, the page reads the `$_GET` variable and use this to fetch posts with that category.

You can use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Comment: it's really nice Steven.Thx for Helping me..:)